# why viewPager.getCurrentItem() return the wrong position?

Tags: android

```
mTabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            isSelected = true;
            showChooseTimeLayout();
            int index = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
            Log.d("out", "index:" + index);
            /* 得到当前的fragment，通过接口回调响应fragment的点击事件 */
            MyFragment myFragment = (MyFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.viewPager + ":" + 1);
            myFragment.setOnShowTimeListener(new MyFragment.OnShowTime() {
                @Override
                public void showTime(String time) {
                    mShowTimeTextView.setText(time);
                }
            });
        }
```

When I click the first tab, this code `int index = viewPager.getCurrentItem();` return "1", when I click the second tab, it return "0", why?

Comment: Index is couted from 0.

Comment: But doesn't the first tab return "0" and the second tab return "1" ?

Comment: Sorry .I think  you should use `viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener` to get the current item of viewpager.

Comment: Thanks.Your method is ok.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you added the listener for the `TabLayout`, but you extracting the selected position from the `ViewPager`.

That might be couple of reasons.

1) Make Sure that you connected the `ViewPager` and the `TabLayout` in an good way

```
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

In this case, you shouldn't add the listener to the `TabLayout`, but on the `ViewPager` instead

2) In case you want separate between the `ViewPager` and the `TabLayout`, so access the selected position from the coming `tab` object from the call back.

Replace

```
int index = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
```

With

```
int index = tab.getPosition();
```